JMX metrics problem with spring-boot-starter-quartz and class loader
I'm running a spring boot (3.3.0) app with a simple quartz job configured with an mssql database (2017). All works correctly.
The app exposes quartz jmx metrics with the property spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true.
When I try to use jconsole to view quartz metrics, I can view metrics only for a few seconds and then both metrics and job stop. This problem is caused by connection pool but it is not normal in my opinion.
But the real problem is that if I try to execute some operation jconsole shows me this error:
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected runtime exception: java.sql.Connection referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
This is the full stack trace from jconsole:
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected runtime exception: java.sql.Connection referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3890)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.pauseJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:2276)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.pauseJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:74)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.pauseJobs(QuartzScheduler.java:1262)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.pauseJobs(QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.java:565)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.pauseJobsAll(QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:262)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at java.management/javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:405)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1405)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)


This is pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

and this is application.properties:
spring.application.name = demo

spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true

# Configurazione JobStore di Quartz
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_

# Configurazione DataSource di Quartz
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=qdb
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=sa
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=********
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=30

I tried to configure some property to make quartz use a specific class loader, but without success. Nothing has changed. Obviously with quartz configured without database, none of these problem show up.
The main problem to solve is the one on the operation execution (about the class loader). Solving this problem the operations called from jconsole would be executed correctly.
And then there is the saturation connections problem, consulting quartz jmx metrics. Solving this problem, metrics will be normally visible.
